# PHP : Upload text file and save content in database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new to php and hope you guys will help me with a situation here..

I have a report file which i have to upload and then save the content to a database.. i have succeed in uploading but failed at saving it in database with separate fields..i can only upload it to 1 fields only

The content of the text file are like this ( with FIXED FORMAT ):

**text.txt**

```
2010000130QUEEN CONSOLIDATED            45119700005794493080171527OLIVER                              800000.0029/01/1622:27:069501
2010000130QUEEN CONSOLIDATED            45119700008408176500068670QUEEN                               500000.0029/01/1622:07:30373L
```

From the above, first 3 columns are for the no,and next 7 for code, 30 for companyname, 16 for userid, 10 for usernumber, 35 for name, 10 for trans, 8 for date, 8 for time and the last is for location..

I've tried so many code but i think this is the closer to my need.The Code looks like the following

**upload.php**

```html
<?php include "header.php";

?>
    
  <form action="do_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <table width="409" height="199" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
                 <td width="161">Upload File (.txt only)</td>
        <td width="14">:</td>
        <td width="218"><input type="file" name="upload"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="3"><button type="submit">Upload</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="3">
      <?php if(!empty($_GET['msg'])){
       echo $_GET['msg'];}
      ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </form>
        
<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

This is my php code which isn't working looks like the following.

**do_upload.php**

```html
<?php include "../connection.php";

 $location_file=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$name_file=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$type_file=$_FILES['upload']['type'];
$size_file=$_FILES['upload']['size'];
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$handle = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],"r");
$lines = explode("\n", $content);

if($location_file==""){
 header("location:upload.php?msg=Please Choose the File");
}else if ($type_file == '.txt'){
 header("location:upload.php?msg=Upload file with .txt extension only");
}else if($size_file > 104857600){
 header("location:upload.php?msg=Max File Size is 100MB");
}
else{
 
 $data = array();
 while (false !== ($line = fgets($handle)))
 {
  $data[] = array(
   'no' => trim(substr($line, 0, 3)),
   'code' => trim(substr($line,3,7)),  
   'companyname' => trim(substr($line, 10, 30)),
   'userid' => trim(substr($line, 40, 16)),
   'usernumber' => trim(substr($line, 56, 10)),
   'name' => trim(substr($line, 66, 35)),
   'trans' => trim(substr($line, 101, 10)),
   'date' => trim(substr($line, 111, 8)),
   'time' => trim(substr($line,119,8)),
   'location' => trim(substr($line,127))
  );
 }
 fclose($handle);
 
 foreach($data as $row){
  $sql="INSERT INTO report (no, code, companyname, userid, usernumber, name, trans, date, time, location) VALUES ('{$row[0]}','{$row[1]}','{$row[2]}','{$row[3]}','{$row[4]}','{$row[5]}','{$row[6]}','{$row[7]}','{$row[8]}','{$row[9]}')";
  if (!mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
  }
 }
 mysqli_close($connect);
 header("location:upload.php?msg=Upload Success! Please View it at 'VIEW REPORT' Menu");
        }
?>
```

Since i'm new to php, i think i should use the `substr()` function and since there will be a white space i'll be using `trim()` since this is a fixed format.

The problem is after i uploaded the text, it insert a blank values into the database. I really don't have any idea what i should do

Please guide me on how to go about it. i'm still a newbie at php, soo any help would be highly appreciated.. Thanks !!

**UPDATE .. Array working but Values not added in Database**

```html
$data[] = array();
  $i = 0;
  while (false !== ($lines = fgets($handle)))
  {
   $data[$i] = array(
       'no' => trim(substr($line, 0, 3)),
       'code' => trim(substr($line,3,7)),  
       'companyname' => trim(substr($line, 10, 30)),
       'userid' => trim(substr($line, 40, 16)),
       'usernumber' => trim(substr($line, 56, 10)),
       'name' => trim(substr($line, 66, 35)),
       'trans' => trim(substr($line, 101, 10)),
       'date' => trim(substr($line, 111, 8)),
       'time' => trim(substr($line,119,8)),
       'location' => trim(substr($line,127))
        );
   $i++;
  }
  fclose($handle);
  
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM,if this not commented then the loop will not work
  /*foreach($data as $data){
   $sql="INSERT INTO report (no, code, companyname, userid, usernumber, name, trans, date, time, location) VALUES ('{$data[0]}','{$data[1]}','{$data[2]}','{$data[3]}','{$data[4]}','{$data[5]}','{$data[6]}','{$data[7]}','{$data[8]}','{$data[9]}')";
   if (!mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
   {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
   }
  }*/
  
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r($data);    Checking the values
  //echo "</pre>";
                mysqli_close($connect);
                header("location:upload.php?msg=Upload Success!");
```

Now that my 'substr()' function works, the only problem is i can't loop when i insert the value to database and i clearly have no idea.. and when i can insert the value it will be inserted like this

[Image inside of phpmyadmin Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWcRN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your $data array for element values.
You can use print_r($data) to see the array elements & values.

Thank you,

Comment: i have checked my $data array, and the value is right there but the data is only the first line from the text file and cannot enter the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO report (no, code, companyname, userid, usernumber, name, trans, date, time, location) VALUES ('{$row['no']}','{$row['code']}','{$row['companyname']}','{$row['userid']}','{$row['usernumber']}','{$row['name']}','{$row['trans']}','{$row['date']}','{$row['time']}','{$row['location']}')";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.